# Angle between two vectors using transpose

Tags: vectors

I came across this in my lecture notes:

$x^{T}y = \left | x \right |\left |  y\right | \cos \theta $

which is confusing as I am only familiar with the dot product equation

[Diagram included in notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pesi.png)

Could anyone clear up the diagram in particular which doesn't make much sense to me?

Comment: $\langle y, x \rangle = y \cdot x = x^T y$

Comment: Try writing $x^Ty$ out in terms of the coordinates and compare it to the dot product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation in your book just shows the dot product in matrix notation. A row vector times a column vector gives you a scalar, the dot product of the row and column vector, as long as the number of columns that the row vector has equals the number of rows that the column vector has. In other words, the row vector must contain the same number of elements as the column vector.  That's a mouthful... so here's an example that can be easy be generalized to any number of elements for x and y (as long as x and y have the same number of elements and are both column vectors).

If x is a column vector, $x^T$ is a row vector:
$$x = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{x_1}}\\
{{x_2}}\\
{{x_3}}
\end{array}} \right]$$

$$y = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{y_1}}\\
{{y_2}}\\
{{y_3}}
\end{array}} \right]$$

$${x^T} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{x_1}}&{{x_2}}&{{x_3}}
\end{array}} \right]$$

$${x^T}y = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{x_1}}&{{x_2}}&{{x_3}}
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{y_1}}\\
{{y_2}}\\
{{y_3}}
\end{array}} \right] = {x_1}{y_1} + {x_2}{y_2} + {x_3}{y_3}$$

In general, if x and y are both $n \times 1$ column vectors,
$$x^Ty = \sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$$

with i representing the ith components of the vectors.

A row times a column is often called the inner product. The outer product is a columns times a row (as long as the vectors have the same number of components...but in that case you get a matrix, not a scalar, as your product. If the column vector was a $n \times 1$ column vector and the row was a $1\times n$ row vector, you'd get an $n \times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 0):

$x^{T}y$ is a vector/matrix notation which correspont precisely to the dot product $x\cdot y=\sum x_iy_i$, indeed

- $x^{T}$ is a row vector 1-by-n
- $y$ is a column vector n-by-1

thus the product, in a vector/matrix sense, is 1-by-1 that's a scalar.